# How to make an array containing strings in a file separated by space?

Tags: perl

I have a file `perl_script_2_out_2.txt` and I want to put all strings separated by space in an array `@arr`.

I wrote this code but isnt working .

```
open my $FILE4, '<', 'perl_script_2_out_2.txt' or die $!;
my @array4 = <FILE4>;
close($FILE4);

open my $FILE5, '>', 'perl_script_2_out_2.txt' or die $!;
foreach $_ (@array4) {
  s/\s+/\n/g;
  print $FILE5 "$_";
}
close($FILE5);

open my $FILE6, '<', 'perl_script_2_out_2.txt' or die $!;
@arr = <$FILE6>;
```

Comment: Does this file have all the fields on a single line? An example would be nice.

Comment: uart_1_baddress  2211   in one line then                                                 uart_2_baddress  3344   in sec line                                                             uart_3_baddress  2572   in third line and so on...

Comment: All on a single line?

Comment: no diffrent lines , with each line containing strings separated by space

Comment: And you want all the fields on all the lines put into a single array?

Comment: yes an array which has all the strings in the whole file..my code is not working

Comment: uart_1_baddress 2211 on one line then uart_2_baddress 3344 on sec line uart_3_baddress 2572 on third line and so according to you since both the words have space between them so they should be pushed to array ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program that you write. In this case you would have seen the message

```
Name "main::FILE4" used only once: possible typo
```

which points to the statement

```
my @array4 = <FILE4>
```

and helps you to see that you have opened the file handle `$FILE4` but tried to read from `FILE4`, which is different.

If you fix that then your code will work, but it's a strange way to do things and it's much better like this. I have used `Data::Dump` to display the final contents of the array; it's not necessary for the program to work.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'perl_script_2_out_2.txt' or die $!;

my @arr;
while (<$fh>) {
  push @arr, split;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \@arr;
```

**output**

```
[
  "uart_1_baddress",
  2211,
  "uart_2_baddress",
  3344,
  "uart_3_baddress",
  2572,
]
```

Comment: open my $fh, '<', 'perl_script_2_out_2.txt' or die $!;

         my @arr;
         while (<$fh>) {
         push @arr, split;
     }
     open my $fh1, '>', 'perl_script_2_out_2.txt' or die $!;
     print $fh1 @arr;
     close($fh1);

Comment: This is what i did and its still giving a blank file

Comment: @Grace90: That works fine for me, but I thought you wanted the data in an array, not in a file.

Comment: Yes in my case it was showing error Can't locate Data/Dump.pm  so i tried to see the array by printing it in the same file but it gave a blank file

Comment: It is best if you install `Data::Dump`, but you could also try `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@arr;`

Comment: Ok but why can't we print the @arr in the file it should work? i mean just instead of use Data::Dump;
dd \@arr;  if i print it in file with rest of program same .

Comment: @Grace90: You can print it to the file. The code in your comment works fine for me, except that all the fields are in a single line with no spaces. Something else is wrong.

Comment: I am so sorry its working fine..by mistake I did some change in the code above this one so my input file was not being generated..just figured out....my bad...thanks a lot for your assistance :)